# Functions too fast? So they get skipped?

Tags: ajax, performance

With a function a div-popover gets called and filled with dynamic data using Ajax, PHP, MySQL and some HTML/CSS. All goes fine.

When I want to delete an entry in the list just popped over it functions as it should. When I send an update request for my list it also goes the way I want it. But, when i call `delete(); update();` right after eachother my first function gets skipped somehow.

When I place `alert()'s` in both functions I see both functions are getting executed and the scripts walk fine through my ajax function, PHP ajax handler and returns the result back to the user, and with the alerts on all is going well too!

So my question is, are my functions too fast? Or is there something I'm missing here which is causing the non-delete?

**Solution** I've moved the `update` call to the line after the `xmlHttp.resonseText` in the `delete` function. In that way the second function call gets executed *after* the first function is done. Thanks all!

Comment: Without relevant code snippets or an example, stripped down to the absolute minimum which reproduces the problem, we can't make anything but wild guesses on what might be going on

Comment: The wild guesses suited ;) I also thought it was more a strategy/principle question rather then an error in my code. Thanks for your comment though! :)

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ gives useful insight into asynchronous JavaScript execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript will just execute the next statement while an ajax call is going on. Most ways of using ajax have an on complete function that you can call, so that code that you want executed after an ajax call is called only afterwards.

I've not worked with php, but it may be worth looking into that.

Comment: You are right. i've placed the update function after the xmlHttp.response, that way they get executed after eachother instead of at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that you haven't thought about the A in AJAX. It stands for asynchronous. That means that when you perform an XmlHttpRequest call, it will be executed in the background. I.e. after you've called `delete();` the script will immediately continue and execute `update();`.

Comment: Asynchronous, JavaScript, And XML.  :-)

I'll upvote you for a more descriptive answer than mine.

Comment: I was only talking about the A. :)

Comment: You're correct, that was the problem. Its solved now. My votes for today are all used, tomorrow I'll vote for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the two methods are executed at the same time (asynchronously) since its AJAX.

you want them to be excuted synchronously.

See this patterns page for more information... [Ajax patterns](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Helpful resource. As I said to the others, my votes for today are all used. Tomorrow I'll give you credits! Thanks again!